# Symfony2 FOS weird redirect after login

Tags: php, symfony

FOS is acting weird in dev environment. After login it sometimes redirects me to `[my page]/_wdt/[smth]`for example `localhost/portal/web/app_dev.php/_wdt/788c84.` . On production env everything works, with no random redirects.

security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider: fos_userbundle
        logout:
              path:   /logout
              target: /
        form_login:
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            csrf_parameter: _csrf_token

            check_path: security_check
            login_path: /login
            default_target_path: frontend_main
            intention: authenticate
            username_parameter: _username
            password_parameter: _password
```

my routing in my bundle / resources/config:

```
frontend_main:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: PortalFrontendBundle:Profile:index }

_profile_main:
    path: /profile
    defaults: { _controller: PortalFrontendBundle:Profile:index }

security_check:
    path: /security_checks
    defaults: { _controller: PortalFrontendBundle:Main:check }

_search:
    path: /search
    defaults: { _controller: PortalFrontendBundle:Profile:search }
    methods: [POST]

_edit_profile:
    path: /profile/edit
    defaults: { _controller: PortalFrontendBundle:Profile:edit }
```

also - when I have routing like that:

```
security_check:
    path: /security_check
    defaults: { _controller: PortalFrontendBundle:Main:check }
```

and security part like that:

```
        check_path: /security_check
```

then I get error that controller should return response ( null given ).

Comment: Have you tried setting `default_target_path: _profile_main` instead? You know that `.../_wdt/788c84` links are Symfony profiler links, if you don't use the profiler in dev mode you can disable it in `conifg.yml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in firewall:

```
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            ...
```

This should stop redirecting to url of type 'wdt'.

Comment: it looks like it helped. Can You explain it a little bit more what happened? :)

Comment: Here is an issue concerning this problem, better documented : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/368 . As I understand it, it is because of the debug toolbar that are behind the firewall you created. This regex here forbids those URL's to be behind the firewall for dev environment.